# kinit errors - authentication to AD 2008

Tags: windows, authentication, active-directory

I am trying to have my application authenticate using AD credentials. I am using kinit to test after creating the krb5.ini file. I believe all the realm information is correct in the ini file but continue to receive the below error when testing with kinit.

```
Exception: krb_error 0 Cannot find any provider supporting ARCFOUR No error
KrbException: Cannot find any provider supporting ARCFOUR
    at
 sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.encrypt(ArcFourHm
 cEType.java:68)
    at
  sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.encrypt(ArcFourHm
    cEType.java:60)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    at sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.<init>(EncryptedData.java:122)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReq.init(KrbAsReq.java:355)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReq.<init>(KrbAsReq.java:180)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.<init>(Kinit.java:253)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.main(Kinit.java:107)
 Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider
 suporting ARCFOUR
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at
  sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.ArcFourCrypto.encrypt(ArcFourCrpto.java:279)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable RC4-HMAC in both your krb5.ini config and the conf/security/java.security

I think RC4 got blacklisted in Oracle JDK (>= 1.8.u060) for known insecurities together with MD5, but it is strictly required for key exchange by the MS Active Directory Kerberos implementation.
Maybe you have to re-enable it by removing RC4 from jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms and jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms of your JDKs conf/security/java.security.

See https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html for more information.